# Freeform 4.2.4 on ExpressionEngine 2.11.2

Tags: solspace-freeform

I cannot get emails sent to my inbox from any of the freeforms.

I have tested EE's communication tool and our server successfully.  It seems that freeform is no longer compatible with this version of EE.

Is there any way to fix this or revert to an older version of Freeform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why EE2.11.2 and Freeform 4.2.4 would work one day and not the next unless something has changed...

As it is (I am guessing) unlikely that you have changed anything in either the EE2.11.2 or Freeform 4.2.4 code, it sounds like something else has changed.  It thus might be worth checking (for example) that nothing has changed on your server (e.g. php version?), or the configuration of your EE installation.

If that investigation doesn't flush any clues out, you could try double-checking your mail setup.  You don't say how your EE installation connects to the mail service you use, but another thing worth trying is to change the mail service or mail server (or both).

Hope you find the problem.  If nothing works, I would recommend considering another option - upgrading EE to the latest version - EE5 is **so** much better than EE2!  The upgrade from EE2 to EE3 is a bit of a game, but much less so these days than it was when EE3 first came out - once you get to EE3 the upgrade to EE5 is usually pretty simple.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  There has been no changes to the server or PHP to my knowledge.  It seems like some emails from a form are going through to our pipedrive account, just not our main email.  I apologize, as I am new to EE.  Where in 2.11 can I access and change where these emails are going? One form is still connected to our old Constant Contact account as well, but I can't find where in the platform to change this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I second @jcogs.eecms on the assessment. It's possible the web host or server admin changed something without your direct knowledge. Also, given that "classic" Freeform doesn't have any built-in integrations, it's possible that your custom **Pipedrive** or **Constant Contact** integrations are playing a role in this (and it _could_ mean that your current Freeform addon is modified, etc, so proceed cautiously if attempting any updates).

Comment: If your EE installation is sending mail correctly via the communicate utility (as you suggest in the question), and from your subsequent information about your setup, it sounds much more likely that the issue is something related to changes in access to either Pipedrive, Constant Contact, or your server platform.  It is unlikely that we'd be able to spot the issue within this kind of forum mediated exchange: if it was me I would start by trying to understand how your setup was intended to work, and then test function for each bit in turn by elimination.